# Perl Junit test cases error

Tags: perl, jenkins

I am trying to execute test cases. So  following code written in my build script.

```
cpanm TAP::Formatter::JUnit
prove --formatter TAP::Formatter::JUnit -lr t > testresults.xml
```

calling this build script from jenkins and added Post-build Actions.  I am getting following error.

```
 **prove --formatter TAP::Formatter::JUnit -lr t
Can't load TAP::Formatter::JUnit at /var/local/maria/hudson/workspace/pigeon-build/target/bin/prove line 11**.
```

Comment: Like *Jeopardy*, all posts to Stack Overflow must be posed in the form of a question.

Comment: I'd liek to take an opportunity remind folks here about the golden rule: Treat others as you wish to be treated.

Comment: You mean "with an expectation of some basic intelligence and the ability to read the FAQ"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using TAP::Harness:JUnit instead, this is how we run it from jenkins, we have jenkins call a script that looks like this:

```
$harness = TAP::Harness::JUnit->new( xmlfile => 'output.xml' );

@tests = qw( t/test1.t t/test2.t ... );
$aggregator = $harness->runtests(@tests);

if(scalar($aggregator->failed())) {
    exit 1;
} else {
    exit 0;
}
```